# Escape "@" / "at" symbol in XSL

Tags: xml, escaping

I am working on an XSLT that takes an email address as a parameter. When **xsltproc** reaches the point in the transform where the value passed in is actually used it fails because the email address contains the "@" symbol:

```
<xsl:template match="revision/author/email"> 
    <xsl:element name="email">
        <xsl:value-of select="$email" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

The output returned is:

```
XPath error : Invalid expression
curses@example.com
```

How can I modify the XSL such that the "@" symbol is escaped properly. Note that I have access to the process that will be providing the input parameter and can also escape it at that point *if* I know what to escape it with.

Comment: Please provide your solution as an answer and accept it. That way your question is seen as resolved, and others can look here if they have a similar problem.

Comment: I've submitted it, apparently can't accept it until tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation the issue is that I was providing the parameter to **xsltproc** using the **--param** argument. Using **--stringparam** instead resolves this issue.